# Manipulate console output stream (add timestamps)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project i need to adjust the unity log file, for readability i need to add timestamps to the output.
For `Debug.Log` output i can add a callback for messages with `Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded` and redirect and modify the output.

But i am using a dll for which i wrote a wrapper. This dll has messages that need to go into my log as well. <strike>From what i understand is that the output will be streamed into the console stream and i know that i can redirect the messages with `Console.SetOut`. But the messages need a timestamp as well and as far as i know there is no way to modify the content of the console stream.</strike>

I know that Unity recently added an argument to include timestamp prefix to logs, but there is no documentation on what the actual command is, and at least in the editor they add the thread ID as well (which i don't need).

I am not sure if it is possible with reflection emit and even if it's, i don't know if that is the best way to go.

currently my script looks something like this:

```
public class ApplicationLogger : Singleton<ApplicationLogger>
{
    string path;
    string file;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private StreamWriter standardOutput;

    void OnEnable()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        if (System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 2)
        {
            path = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2] + @"/log";
            file = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2] + @"/log/Unity.log";
        }
        Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += HandleLog;
#endif
        
        standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
        writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        Console.SetOut(writer);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        Console.SetOut(standardOutput);

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded -= HandleLog;
#endif
    }

    void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(() => WriteFile(logString, stackTrace, type));
    }

    void WriteFile(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {

        writer.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}] " + logString);
        if (LogType.Error == type || LogType.Exception == type)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(stackTrace);
        }
        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

<strike>With this i at least have all the messages i need, but only the Unity output has timestamps.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement your own stream writer?

```
class MyTextWriter : System.IO.StreamWriter
{
    public MyTextWriter(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        base.WriteLine($"[{System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}] {value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: because that would mean that the dll would need to use my streamwriter, but i have no control over what they use.

Comment: No, the DLL need to use `Console.WriteLine(balabala)`, and you need to use `Console.SetOut(new MyTextWriter(log))`

Comment: oh,  but the dll is written in c, so it's probably `printf()`, will that work aswell?

Comment: No, if so data are written to `standardOutput`, your current approach won't receive these messages too.